# Give an angle to a servomotor

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, wiringpi

I have my servomotor conencted to my raspberry pi and I have set wiringPi but I'm only able to make it turn. I'm searching for a way to give him a specific angle.

The code I'm using to make it turn:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <wiringPi.h>
    
    int main() {
        printf ("Raspberry Pi wiringPi test program\n");
        wiringPiSetupGpio();
        pinMode (18, l) ;
        pwmSetMode (PWM_OUTPUT);
        pwmSetRange (1024);
        pwmSetClock (375);
        pwmWrite(18, 10);
    
    }
```

Comment: Is it a positional rotation or continuous rotation servo motor? Or by "only able to make it turn", do you really mean that you're able to hold a position, but not a specific one?

Comment: Servos typically require position feedback.

Comment: It's this one [link](https://www.gotronic.fr/art-servomoteur-s4303r-20725.htm) and it should hold a position